# return value from js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have two `js` file in my `html` page . If the first one begins with :

```
 (function($){
   ..  
   ..
   }(jQuery));
```

can I insert a `var` into `function($,varname)` , `return` it's value and use it in the other file?

Comment: not `return`, but you can assign it as a property of `window`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a global variable for this.  You can do this in one of a few ways.  Let's assume we need to send the value "Bacon" to the other script.

```
(function($){
   window.myScriptsExports = "Bacon";
}(jQuery));

// OR

var myScriptsExports = (function($){
   // other code
   return "Bacon";
   // NO other code
}(jQuery));

// OR (not really recommended)

(function($){
   // other code
   $.myScriptsExports = "Bacon";
   // other code
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can improve the code by using global namespace which goes like:

```
    (function($,global){
       var _obj = {};
       _obj.property1 = 'Property1';
       _obj.function1 = function() { console.log('Function 1');};
       global.myObject = _obj;
     }(jQuery,window));

     //accessing
     window.myObject.property1
     //or
     window.myObject.function1()
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your function is synchrone, you may set a global function :

```
   (function($){
   .. 
      var myvar = 666; 
      window.getMyVar = function() {
         return myvar;
      };
   ..
   }(jQuery));
```

and you can use it from the other function if the second file is imported after this one :

```
   (function($){
   .. 
      var myprevisouslysetvar = window.getMyVar();
   ..
   }(jQuery));
```

Note that the files doesn't matter in javascript : your page would work the same (apart details if you have "use strict") with both files concatenated.